# Create arbitrary size JavaScript/TypeScript 2d array in one line

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

How would I create an m×n 2d array in JavaScript or TypeScript? Of course, I could create a 2×3 array with:

```js
arr = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

But the dimensions are given to me in variables `m` and `n`. So I can do the following:

```js
arr = new Array(m).fill(new Array(n).fill(0))
```

But the rows are all the same array:

```js
arr[1][2] = 5
console.table(arr)
```

| (index) | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

I only modified the bottom row, but the top row was affected as well. So the following does what I want (each cell is a different memory location):

```js
arr = [...new Array(2)].map(() => new Array(3).fill(0))
```

This works, but it's pretty ugly. Does JavaScript or TypeScript have a more appropriate or efficient way to create 2d arrays?

Comment: The question is different, but one of the answers was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
let arr = Array.from({length: 3}, () => Array(3).fill(0))

arr[1][2] = 5

console.log(arr)
```